# How to bind neo4j to IP address not with localhost

Tags: neo4j

I have installed neo4j community edition 3.0.1. It is bound to localhost.
I want to bind it to IP address.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the different IP address. You just go to the conf/neo4j.conf and change the localhost:7474 to your specific IP:7474

I'm using the neo4j 3.04 + Java 1.8.